# oracle Apex, Issue with Ajax call

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

In Oracle Apex 5.1, I am having issues with Ajax call in my code. There is no error shown as well. Request help in debugging the below scenario.

I created a report with check boxes. This page also has 4 buttons A, B, C, D. I created a page process which is a pl/sql block. Upon clicking on bUtton A OR B this process is being called and executed properly as expected.

For buttons C and D, I wanted to take a user input and pass it to page process.After that only, the process should get executed. For this, I have written an on click dynamic action which prompts for user input upon clicking on buttons C or D.

```
    var order= prompt("Please enter order number", "");
    $s('P1_UPDATED_ORDER_NUMBER',order);
    alert ($v(P1_UPDATED_ORDER_NUMBER)); // Until this the code is working 

    apex.server.process ('my_process',{}, {"dataType": "text"});
```

In the above code, the last line is not showing any result or error. I am not sure if the call is actually made or not?

Answer (score 0):

This issue is resolved by removing apex.server.process()  and triggering page submit after above java script is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the actual solution to request the AJAX Callback is to use this:

```
apex.server.process ('my_process',null, {"dataType": "script"});
```